# is it possbile to download one part of a file from web ?

Tags: linux, download

lets say there is one very big file on some server and i just want to download first 1MB.
How can I do it on Linux ?

Comment: not suitable for stackoverflow. maybe superuser?

Comment: ok. I will copy to superuser.

Comment: Don't copy it, it'll get migrated there if it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server supports it, `curl -o filename -r 0-1048575 http://url/to/file` will just download the first MB.

Comment: This is stackoverflow and not superuser, so you should have suggested to use libcurl .... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really have anything to do with Linux, but rather is part of the HTTP protocol.  Yes, you can resume a file transfer from an arbitrary offset, and abort it whenever you like.

One way to do this on Linux is to cancel a download after 1MB is complete.  For instance, start a `wget`, and when the output reaches 1MB in size, kill it.